# How can I add items to an empty set in python

Tags: python, set

I have the following procedure:

```
def myProc(invIndex, keyWord):
    D={}
    for i in range(len(keyWord)):
        if keyWord[i] in invIndex.keys():
                    D.update(invIndex[query[i]])
    return D
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

I do not get any error if D contains elements. But I need D to be empty at the beginning.

Comment: `{}` is a dictionary, not a set.

Comment: With a line `D={}` you declare an empty dictionary, not a set. You declare an empty set by `S=set()`.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546259/how-to-add-integer-input-in-a-set-object?noredirect=1&lq=1 Please see my answer for this over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269760/14750782

Answer (score 204, accepted):

`D = {}`  is a dictionary not set.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
```

Use  `D =  set()`:

```
>>> d = set()
>>> type(d)
<type 'set'>
>>> d.update({1})
>>> d.add(2)
>>> d.update([3,3,3])
>>> d
set([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> D = set()
>>> type(d)
<type 'dict'>
>>> type(D)
<type 'set'>
```

What you've made is a dictionary and not a Set.

The `update` method in dictionary is used to update the new dictionary from a previous one, like so,

```
>>> abc = {1: 2}
>>> d.update(abc)
>>> d
{1: 2}
```

Whereas in sets, it is used to add elements to the set.

```
>>> D.update([1, 2])
>>> D
set([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a variable to empty curly braces {} eg: `new_set = {}`, it becomes a dictionary. 
To create an empty set, assign the variable to a 'set()' ie: `new_set = set()`