# how to add integer input in a set object

Tags: python-3.7

unable to add an item into a set taking it as an input from user

```
input>>j=set()
input>>j.add(int(input()))
```

### 4

TypeError: descriptor 'add' requires a 'set' object but received a 'int'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add items to an empty set in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511270/how-can-i-add-items-to-an-empty-set-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do it:

1. `j = set()` 
   `j.add(a)` # a can be anything. If you want integer you can type cast it with int()
2. `j = {''}` # initializing a set in this way requires some default parameter otherwise python will make it a dictionary
   `j.add(1)` or 
   `j.add(a)` # where a is an integer
   `j.remove('')` # remove the initial string that we added

Answer (score 0):

It because you have to call it to get a set

```
j = set()
j.add(int(input()))
```

Comment: i called it ...j=set()

Comment: Well the code I have provided is working. If you have error messages, the root cause is elsewhere. Can you provide more of the code that you have?